# Python no reconoce modulo instalado

Tags: python-3.x, pip, module.exports

Estoy empezando a aprender ciencia de datos con python en Mac.OS utilizando Visual Studio Code. Utilizando la terminal y pip3 ya he instalado algunos módulos como Networkx, hoy intente utilizar las bibliotecas seaborn y Jinja2 pero me da los errores ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn', ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'Jinja2' respectivamente. Ya intente desinstalar las bibliotecas y volverlas a instalar pero sigue el problema.

Adjunto capturas de pantalla de la terminal al ejecutar el comando pip3 list.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo solucionar mi problema? Agradecería si alguien me pudiera explicar como evitar este tipo de problemas en un futuro.

Gracias de antemano, Saludos

Comment: Buen día, es probable que la versión de python en Visual Studio Code y en tu terminal sean diferentes, ejecuta `import sys print(sys.version)` en VSC y en la terminal y revisa si ambas son iguales

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. Ya hice lo que comentas y en efecto tengo versiones diferentes en VSC 3.10.4 y en la terminal 3.9.12. Ya estoy actualizando python. Gracias :)

Comment: usa el comentario de heytalpazguato como respuesta y cierra la pregunta para que otros les sirva